# What is the difference between fixtures and support files in Cypress? Which one is better to use?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Both *fixtures* and support files store static data, right? What is the best recommended to use?

Comment: No, fixtures are static data whereas support is for reusable *behaviour*, see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A use case for `fixtures` could be to put static data that is used during a test, such as a JSON body.

Say you need to store some request body JSON that you're going to be using a lot. It won't change much and doesn't need to be changed by tests.
`requestBody.json` could be stored in `fixtures` and then in the test spec the `.json` could be referenced and then used in a test. Files in `cypress/fixtures/` are not meant to change or be dynamic in the tests:

```
const requestBody = require("../fixtures/requestBody.json");

describe('Test', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: myUrl,
      body: requestBody
    })....
```

---

A use case for `support` could be to define a Custom Command in `cypress/support/commands.js`.

Say you need to send a header with some data that you don't want to expose, such as an Authorization key. You also need to hardcode the `GET` method, but you want to leave the `url` and `body` to be dynamic. A Custom Command could be defined in `cypress/support/commands.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getRequestWithSecret', (url, body) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: mySecretKey
        },
        url: url,
        body: body
    });
});
```

and then this Custom Command can be used in the code. You can see in the example below there is a mixture of static and dynamic content. The fixture being imported, as well as the Custom Command. `getRequestWithSecret` is dynamic because it is accepting inputs.
`cypress/support/index.js` and `commands.js` get loaded before the test spec starts. This is pretty useful because it means that you can add scripts that can run before tests start. So these don't need to be imported into your tests at runtime.

```
const requestBody = require("../fixtures/requestBody");

describe('Test', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    cy.getRequestWithSecret({
      url: myUrl,
      body: requestBody
    })....
```

Answer (score 2):

Both have different purposes. Fixtures are used as external pieces of static data that can be used by your tests whereas the support file is a great place to put reusable behavior such as custom commands or global overrides that you want to be applied and available to all of your spec files.
For more better understanding, I recommend you to read the cypress official docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Support-file

Answer (score 1):

[Fixture](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax) is static data that is needed for tests - usually we put images, JSON files, and some downloadable fixtures there.

In support files we add/customize commands, and import [Plugins](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/) and other dependencies needed for the test. It can also be used to make some initial setup, like before/beforeAll functions, but this part is better made in configuration files or directly in the tests.